# What is this element on the eee pc 701 motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I have an eee pc 701 motherboard:

[image]

and I accidentally dropped it.. :D

So the THING (copper/circle) has fallen off. (don't laugh)

**QUESTION#**: what is this copper circle called? (IMHO I can go to a shop and buy this part, and then "solder" it to the motherboard.. )

UPDATE: ok, it's an inductor (thanks for this) - but what is it's exact name? :P :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that that "THING" is a type of inductor, probably used to regulate power to the CPU/RAM. Whether it is critical is another question, which I do not know the answer to.
Going on the assumtion that it regulates power, I would say there is a reasonably good chance that you could either fry your RAM/CPU or it would do nothing without it.

If you still have the original part, I would try to solder it back on. From my experience, parts like that very rarely have identifying numbers on them to see about replacing them (although sometimes it will tell you something about it on the motherboard itself, look for white lettering under or next to the part).

Comment: It certainly is an inductor. Resoldering would not be difficult. My concern though would be that whatever impact that ripped the component off damaged the traces in the process. After resoldering you would want to check continuity to the components that are connected to either side of the inductor (using the schematic definition of 'connected')